# Recording audio from user's microphone in silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, audio

Does anyone know if it is possible? Does silverlight 3 support recording from the client's microphone?

Comment: This feature has certainly been added in Silverlight 4. Silverlight 4 doesn't _directly_ answer your question since it is about Silverlight 3, but Silverlight 4 will get you there now that it has been released.

Answer (score 4):

Just to verify Noldorin's answer 'officially' -- it is currently NOT possible in Silverlight 3 as a plugin only.  This (webcam/mic) is something we're exploring for Silverlight future versions and is a highly requested feature.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly not on the [*What's New*](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight3/default.aspx) list for Silverlight 3, which is a complete listing of significant new features in the latest version. This would with little doubt seem to indicate the answer is *no*, it's not possible.

Indeed, audio (and video) recording is a feature that's been highly desired since the release of Silverlight 2, and is one of the very few respects in which Silverlight is found lacking when compared to Flash. I would imagine it's quite likely to be added as a feature of Silverlight 4, if it keeps getting the high demand from developers. I'm not sure why Microsoft hasn't bothered yet; perhaps it is simply not high on their priority list, or they're worried about the security issues (though Flash has resolved this quite well).